# `yarn upgrade` on React Typescript NextJS app "element type 'ReactElement<any, any> | Component<{}, any, any> | null' is not a valid JSX element"

Tags: reactjs, typescript, types, next.js

I'm working on a React Typescript NextJS app. Had to upgrade NextJS due to the image cache issue (not related). I've managed to sort that, but... my colleague suggested running yarn upgrade, and now I'm seeing this error when we build. Assuming something @types/some-package isn't right? Or something not compatible so yarn has installed an older version of something in a dependency maybe?

Full error below. What I've done so far:

```
yarn upgrade
rm yarn.lock
rm -rf node_modules
yarn install
```

Same error! A bit stuck with where to start looking as this error seems to be happen to loads of things after yarn upgrade. Few red herrings I've got stuck with already. Can anyone give me a steer?

```
./src/components/AuthenticatedApp.tsx:29:10
Type error: 'Layout' cannot be used as a JSX component.
  Its element type 'ReactElement<any, any> | Component<{}, any, any> | null' is not a valid JSX element.
    Type 'Component<{}, any, any>' is not assignable to type 'Element | ElementClass | null'.
      Type 'Component<{}, any, any>' is not assignable to type 'ElementClass'.
        The types returned by 'render()' are incompatible between these types.
          Type 'React.ReactNode' is not assignable to type 'import("/Users/blah/blah-src/app-name/node_modules/@types/react-transition-group/node_modules/@types/react/index").ReactNode'.

  27 |       <StoreProvider readKey={readKey} login={login}>
  28 |         <PageLoadingProgress />
> 29 |         <Layout>
     |          ^
  30 |           <Component {...pageProps} />
  31 |         </Layout>
  32 |       </StoreProvider>
```

For info - all component files are .tsx and any utils are .ts.

Package.json that I can share:

```
  "dependencies": {
    "@azure/msal-browser": "^2.21.0",
    "@azure/msal-react": "^1.2.0",
    "@cloudnative/health-connect": "^2.1.0",
    "@emotion/react": "^11.7.1",
    "@emotion/styled": "^11.6.0",
    "@material-ui/core": "^4.12.3",
    "@mui/icons-material": "^5.3.0",
    "@mui/lab": "^5.0.0-alpha.65",
    "@mui/material": "^5.3.0",
    "apicache": "^1.6.3",
    "connect": "^3.7.0",
    "country-language": "^0.1.7",
    "date-fns": "^2.28.0",
    "express": "^4.17.2",
    "framer-motion": "^5.6.0",
    "lodash": "^4.17.21",
    "next": "^12.1.0",
    "passport": "^0.5.2",
    "passport-azure-ad": "^4.3.1",
    "react": "^17.0.2",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.2",
    "react-flag-kit": "^1.0.0",
    "react-hook-form": "^7.25.3",
    "react-intersection-observer-hook": "^2.0.3",
    "react-text-transition": "^1.3.0",
    "react-topbar-progress-indicator": "^4.1.0",
    "sass": "^1.48.0",
    "wget": "^0.0.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.16.7",
    "@storybook/addon-actions": "^6.4.13",
    "@storybook/addon-essentials": "^6.4.13",
    "@storybook/addon-links": "^6.4.13",
    "@storybook/react": "^6.4.13",
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.16.1",
    "@testing-library/react": "^12.1.2",
    "@types/apicache": "^1.6.1",
    "@types/connect": "^3.4.35",
    "@types/express": "^4.17.13",
    "@types/lodash": "^4.14.178",
    "@types/passport": "^1.0.7",
    "@types/passport-azure-ad": "^4.3.1",
    "@types/react": "17.0.38",
    "@us/prettier-config": "^2.1.0",
    "babel-jest": "^27.4.6",
    "babel-loader": "^8.2.3",
    "eslint": "8.7.0",
    "eslint-config-next": "12.0.8",
    "eslint-plugin-simple-import-sort": "^7.0.0",
    "eslint-plugin-unused-imports": "^2.0.0",
    "husky": "^7.0.4",
    "jest": "^27.4.7",
    "lint-staged": "^12.3.3",
    "prettier": "^2.5.1",
    "storybook-addon-material-ui": "^0.9.0-alpha.24",
    "tsconfig-paths-webpack-plugin": "^3.5.2",
    "typescript": "4.5.4"
  }
```

Had a few goes at updating small bits of code, but dont want to have to re-type loads of components. Any help appreciated.

More info, Layout.tsx looks like:

```
import type { NextPage } from 'next'; 
...
const Layout: NextPage = ({ children }) => {

return <Blah>{children}</Blah>;
}
```

Comment: What does the function signature for your `Layout` component look like? I.e., how are its type annotations applied?

Comment: @MarkG - updated question because I couldn't format it in here...

Comment: `NextPage` should only be used for _page_ components, which `Layout` is not.

Comment: Good point, I will adress...